# Make a line from a point to every point on a curve to create a surface

Tags: modeling, geometry

Shown below is an image. The requirement is simple. I want a way to make a bunch of lines from point A to every point on circle B ( that would form a conical surface) and also extrapolate those lines to as far beyond the circle as I want.

B could be anything, a square, a pentagon or any other enclosed or unclosed curve.
There could also be multiple such starting points (A) and multiple curves (B) to which lines are to be drawn in the same scene (for lack of a better word). Analyzing the intersection between these surfaces is crucial. I don't know if Blender is the best tool for the job but eventually, I'd give thickness to these surfaces and export a 3D model.

Needless to say I'm very new to Blender.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode select all the verts on **B**, press <kbd>e</kbd> to extrude, then right-click to cancel movement, then press <kbd>s</kbd> to scale, and type 0 to collapse all the newly extruded points. Move these points to **A**.

The reselect the verts on **B**, press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to grab and slide, and hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> to disable clamping.

Comment: Your first part worked like a charm. Thank you so much for that. I'm one step closer to what I'm trying to do. But the second part doesn't do what I was going for. 

I was hoping for something like edge slide (gg - hotkey), but slide beyonf the actual curve along the normal.

Comment: @VipulRajan press GG, slide up, then press and hold ALT and slide down.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. 

I could do it with a cirlce. Now I just need to figure out how to make squares and other shapes in Blender but that should be relatively simple. Again. Thanks a whole lot

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady I kind of rushed writing this answer and typo'd the gg part.